# Error in installing Symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, installation, frameworks

I am new to Symfony skeleton. Can anyone please help to get out from this error for installation of Symfony? I had searched a lot on the internet but cannot find any working solutions. Composer is working well. I am using PHP7 and XAMP server.

Error is Could not find package Symfony/skeleton with stability Stable in a version installable using your PHP version 7.0.2.
[image]

Comment: Need at least 7.1.3 to install.  Best to jump directly to 7.2 though.

Answer (score 1):

Cerad's answer is correct. Please check [Requirements for Running Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html)

It states the following:

> Symfony 4.0 requires PHP 7.1.3 or higher to run, in addition to other minor requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to live with `php7.0`, you are able to install the symfony demo project via `symfony installer`, see [how to install symfony installer for sf3.4](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup.html).

After you have installed `sf installer`, you can install the demo project with old symfony version by doing:

`$ symfony new blog 3.0.1`

As mentioned by Cerad, you need have php7.1 or newest php version to install latest symfony demo project. But you can also have a try to install the demo project with older version by doing:

`$ composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton:3.3`

you can find the the release version which you need [here](https://github.com/symfony/website-skeleton/releases?after=v4.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your Php version from 7.02 to upper version.
I had the same issue, my **path variable** was pointing at **php7.0.**, change it to **php7.2.** and the problem solved immediatly.

**Important** : Don't forget to restart you terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem not being able to find 4.4 without php version part.
In case some one comes in contact with this (As I did), installing [Symfony CLI](https://symfony.com/download) and using it instead of direct composer, might solve the problem.

I was actually able to install Symfony 4.4 project as below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton:"^6.0" yourProjetName
```

try to specify the version 6.0 
It solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while installing **Symfony Demo App** (Symfony 6). If your PHP runtime has passed `symfony check:requirements`, you may want to enable `PDO-SQLite PHP extension` or other project requirements such as the supported PHP version - [Symfony Demo's Requirements](https://github.com/symfony/demo#requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that OP's goal is to setup and install Symphony, according to [Synfony's Official Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html) there are various ways one can go about doing it.

First of all, make sure one is satisfying all the requirements. For my example I will be using the most recent versions of Symphony and PHP:

> - Install PHP 8.1 or higher and these PHP extensions (which are
>   installed and enabled by default in most PHP 8 installations): [Ctype](https://www.php.net/book.ctype),
>   [iconv](https://www.php.net/book.iconv), [PCRE](https://www.php.net/book.pcre), [Session](https://www.php.net/book.session), [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/book.simplexml), and [Tokenizer](https://www.php.net/book.tokenizer);
> - [Install Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/), which is used to install PHP packages.
>
> Optionally, you can also [install Symfony CLI](https://symfony.com/download). This creates a binary called symfony that provides all the tools you need to develop and run your Symfony application locally.

In this case, it seems that OP has already installed both PHP and composer, however OP might have to update the PHP version ([as Cerad mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49472162/error-in-installing-symfony4#comment85947206_49472162)).

Now, depending on one's goals, there are different ways to move one:

1. If one is building a traditional web application open the CMD or Git Bash, and run

   ```
   composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"6.1.*" my_project_directory
   ```

Then

```
cd my_project_directory
```

And

```
composer require webapp
```

2. If one is building a microservice, console application or API, then open the CMD or Git Bash and run

   ```
   composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"6.1.*" my_project_directory
   ```

---

**Notes:**

- In both cases, by specifying the version shouldn't give us the error that OP is facing.
- If error keeps on appearing, would recommend using CMD or Git Bash as I've tried here and worked fine with both.

Answer (score -2):

you forgot to specify the installation folder. Use a dot to install in the current folder.

Comment: Symfony/Composer will actually create a default directory if you don't specify one.